# JAX-WS dateTime with nanoseconds

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, xsd, jax-ws

Does JAX-WS support nanoseconds for xml type dateTime?
And does W3C allow it?

When client sends:
    2015-06-11T09:02:15.863432
The server endpoint sees an unmarshalled jaxb object with the value
     2015-06-11T09:02:15.863

I have mapped dateTime to String to see if I can receive the String value on my endPoint and I cannot.  Something in JAX-WS is stripping the last three digits before it reaches my endpoint.

```
<xsd:element name="my_ts" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>

<jaxb:globalBindings>
    <jaxb:javaType name="java.lang.String" xmlType="xsd:dateTime"/>
</jaxb:globalBindings>
```

W3C says durations have a limitation of millisecond, but I don't see such a limitation on dateTime.

I am running java EE 6 with Weblogic 12.

Comment: W3C allows it: "Additional digits can be used to increase the precision of fractional seconds if desired i.e the format ss.ss... **with any number of digits after the decimal point is supported**." from http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#dateTime

Comment: Additonal Info:  If I add a Logical Handler to the handler chain, the nanoseconds are there in the LogicalHandler.  So they are getting stripped by the jax-ws servlet after the handler chain has completed.  Certainly I could store them on the thread, but that seems like an ugly work around.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `xsd:dateTime` should be mapped to `XMLGregorianCalendar` and you should be able to use the `getFractionalSecond()` method to get sub-millisecond precision.

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear.  The fractions are getting stripped somewhere.  The string that is passed to the endpoint has had the fractional seconds stripped before reaching the endpoint.  It's not an issue with the use of the XMLGregorianCalendar

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to add a file to my META-INF services folder called

```
com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory
```

And then, within that file I put the following line

```
com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextFactory
```

It turns out that weblogic 12 uses eclipselink as the jax-ws binding provider.  There is a bug in the EclipseLink unmarshaller with regard to more than 3 digits of fractional second precision on the DateTime XML type.  The reason that my handlers could see the whole string was that I had already been poiting to the glassfish unmarshaller in my jaxb provider.

Once I changed providers, my adapter was able to see and parse all of the fractional second digits.